# Raspberry Pi: Temperature read-out remotely from Computer

Tags: raspbian, python, remote, temperature

I'm using my Raspberry Pi a lot for different applications and am normally running Python scrips on it to control the Raspberry Pi. I now have a problem that I couldn't find out how to solve.
I have several controllers connected to my Windows computer and am recording different parameters from different controllers (I'm researcher and need to record different parameters, none of the controllers is a raspberry pi so far).
However, it would be great to measure the room temperature and humidity as well as I record other parameter and I was wondering if I can directly connect to my Raspberry Pi and remotely read out the temperature and humidity and directly have the values stored on my Windows computer?

The only problem that I have is that it is unclear to me how to access the Raspberry Pi by Python (run from my Windows computer), do a readout and store the value directly on my computer.

Comment: I suggest having the necessary sensors connected to the Pi, with a python script that will save the output from them to a text file. You'll then need a piece of code that will have the file sent from the Pi to your Windows computer. There are plenty of tutorials out there for a setup like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library has a [Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) which can run on Windows and will communicate with the pigpio [daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) running on one or more Pis.

This allows your Windows (or Mac or Linux) box to run a Python script which talks to the GPIO on one or more networked Pis.

As long as your sensors use the GPIO, or I2C, or SPI there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just a question: how do I automatically run the pigpio deamon when the raspberry pi starts up? I basically have just to enter "sudo pigpiod" in the command line, but is there a way it automatically does it?

Comment: I've found the solution. the easiest is to add it to the crontab. by entering "sudo crontab -e" one can edit it by adding an extra line "@reboot /usr/local/bin/pigpiod"